# Download file after ajax post call in .NET

Tags: .net, ajax, excel

My objective is to download an excel file after an ajax POST call. So far I have this endpoint which generates the excel file I want:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ExportReportList(ReportFilterViewModel filter, RequestedPageInfo pageInfo)
    {
        IEnumerable<RtbReport> rtbs = null;

        // get collection of page view entities to supply to the exporter
        rtbs = RtbReportRepository.GetReport(filter).ToList();

        // put in default values for null-valued numberic fields
        rtbs = rtbs.ToList()
                             .Select(s =>
                             {
                                 s.AdvertiserId = s.AdvertiserId ?? 0;
                                 s.CampaignId = s.CampaignId ?? 0;
                                 s.RtbCampaignId = s.RtbCampaignId ?? 0;
                                 s.CapLoss = s.CapLoss ?? 0.0M;
                                 s.GrossRevenue = s.GrossRevenue ?? 0.0M;
                                 s.GrossProfit = s.GrossProfit ?? 0.0M;
                                 s.GrossProfitPerc = s.GrossProfitPerc ?? 0.0M;

                                 return s;
                             });


        // export the report as an XLS binary format
        byte[] output = GetReportListExcel(rtbs);

        // export as an excel MIME type
        return File(output, "application/vnd.ms-excel", "RtbReport.xls");

    }
```

I want to download this file I have generated. What is the path I am supposed to hit to prompt the download of RtbReport.xls? From some of the answers I looked up, many of them use window.location and specified a path to the file. However, I can't for the life of me figure out what path the file is located on.

Answer (score 0):

How you are posting data to this action.

If it is normal form post from client browser then file will be downloaded to browser.

If it is an ajax request then you won't be able to download the file as response is sent to ajax success callback. You need to simulate normal browser form post from your javascript (framework) to work will ajax calls.

Please post client code for more detail. ALSO, THERE IS NO FILE ON YOUR SERVER. IT WILL BE CREATED AS BINARY PER REQUEST INSTANCE ONLY AND WILL BE SENT TO CLIENT.